# JQuery Game Button Generator

Tags: jquery, button, random, numbers, coordinates

I have been looking for ages for a game idea I have. I have just started off with JQuery and I want to know how to make a game where you click a button then it respawns in a different position.

All I know is that I would have too make a canvas then generate 2 numbers in the canvas then move it to that position.

How can this be done?

Comment: You could use javascript `Math.random();` to generate your random coordinates but I think you need to flesh out your idea a little and provide the code of what you already tried so we can help.

Comment: `$('button').click(function() { $(this).css({top: Math.random()*100, left: Math.random()*100}); });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done very simply by manipulating the CSS applied to the button. Here is an example:

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button").on("click", function(){
        var widthMax = $(window).width() - $("#button").width();
        var heightMax = $(window).height() - $("#button").height();

        var randomLeft = Math.random() * (widthMax);
        var randomTop = Math.random() * (heightMax);

        $("#button").css("left", randomLeft).css("top", randomTop);
    });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<input type="button" style="position: absolute;" id="button" value="Click Me" />
```

Comment: Thanks so much everyone. This is the first time I have ever used this service and you guys helped so much! I will be helping out around here too. Once again thanks.